# According to Shi'ites, are 'Sunni' hadith collections reliable?

Tags: hadith, shia-sunni, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Particularly concerning the two most famous texts on hadith in Islam, al-Bukhari and Muslim.

If not, why not? And what are the go-to hadith books in the Shi'ite followers of Islam?

Answer (score 1):

Salam on alaykom.

You said 2 books of 6 sources of Sunni hadiths : صحاح سته

> sahih bokhari ,  sonan termezi ,  sahih moslem ,  sonan aboo davood , 
>   sonan nesaei ,  sonan ibn maje

All of hadiths in these are not reliable, but all of them are not kezb.
For example in source of Shias we see some hadiths is referred to Sunni sources.

**Shia sources are:**

- من لا یحضره الفقیه say "man la yahzorohol faqih" -> sheikh sadooq
- التهذیب say "tahzib" -> sheikh toosi
- الاستبصار say "estebsar" -> sheikh toosi
- اصول الکافی say "kafi" -> sheikh koleini